# Creating a function in C that ask for inputs and outputs, then calling that function in main?

Tags: c, function, int

I have a very basic question. I am trying to Refactor my code so that instead of asking for a input and scanning the input in main, I want to create a input function that ask the questions and call that function in main. Now I am trying to think about the parameters and I think I am just not understanding how they work in this Scenario, For now I left them blank, this code compiles perfectly but when I run it, all it does is print the stuff I have in main and not doing what I want for the function (I added some print lines as a debug tool so I can know if my function is being hit or not.They all get printed out so its something wrong with the function itself)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sample_function_test();
    printf("It reaches this far\n");
    printf("Data demonstrator program by Me\n");
    int in_decimal();
    printf("It reaches this far\n");
    int out_decimal();
    printf("It reaches this far\n");
    /*Called the funtions above gets input and shows output*/ 
    /*Says to do it Twice*/ 
    int in_decimal();
    int out_decimal();      
    return 0;
}
/*Function In Decimal,Reads user inputed number*/

int in_decimal()
{
    int dec_input;
    printf("Please type an int in decimal:");
    scanf("%d",&dec_input);
    return dec_input;
}

/*Function Out Decimal, Outputs user inputed number*/

int out_decimal()
{
    int dec_input;
    printf("Output in decimal:%d\n", dec_input);
    return dec_input;
}
int sample_function_test()
{
    printf("testing function call");
}
```

Comment: You're 'out_xxx' functions are not displaying the values associated with the 'in_xxx' functions. The variables declared are local to each procedure, eg dec_input is a distinct variable in each method. You need to pass that as as parameter among your functions. You're also not capturing the value returned from your functions.

Answer (score 2):

`int in_decimal();` is a function declaration, not a function call. You need to call the function with `in_decimal();` instead. The same goes for the other functions.

You probably also want to put the returned value somewhere, e.g.

```
x = in_decimal();
```

You should also put either a declaration for the called functions (`int in_decimal();`, etc.), or the functions themselves, before `main`.

Answer (score 0):

So Would this be right? Since its grabbing that dec_input as a parameter and using that exact number obtained from the scan in the input function?
    #include

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    in_decimal();
    out_decimal();
    /*Called the funtions above gets input and shows output*/ 
    /*Says to do it Twice*/ 
    in_decimal();
    out_decimal();      
    return 0;
}
/*Function In Decimal,Reads user inputed number*/
int in_decimal(void)
{
    int dec_input;
    printf("Please type an int in decimal:");
    scanf("%d",&dec_input);
    return dec_input;
}

/*Function Out Decimal, Outputs user inputed number*/

int out_decimal(dec_input)
{
    printf("Output in decimal:%d\n", dec_input);
    return dec_input;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out, I didn't see I was initializing the function again in main, taking out the int's fixes this.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    in_decimal();
    out_decimal();
    /*Called the funtions above gets input and shows output*/ 
    /*Says to do it Twice*/ 
    in_decimal();
    out_decimal();      
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your basic problem has not been resolved. in_decimal() reads and returns a value that is never returned to the calling program in main(). If out_decimal is printing the correct value, it's a coincidence. The value returned by in_decimal() is lost in both cases.

Comment: So If I have to use that same input I would  have the parameter of the second function out_decimal be (dec_input)? also in terms of figuring out the intuition of where exactly I should initialize the int dec_input is a little confusing. It works when I put it in the first function I created. But putting it in the main before declaring any functions doesn't. But for the output I dont have to declare it I think mainly because its already been declared by the first function since we wanna use that same input. Also Do I have to assign it to a variable like x = in_decimal(); thats only if I want it